# Encoding and decoding in Python with MD5( )

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

Running this code on Ubuntu 10.10 in Python 3.1.1

I am getting the following error:

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte**

And the position of the error changes depending on when I run the following code:
(not the real keys or secret)

```
sandboxAPIKey = "wed23hf5yxkbmvr9jsw323lkv5g"
sandboxSharedSecret = "98HsIjh39z"

def buildAuthParams():
    authHash = hashlib.md5();

    #encoding because the update on md5() needs a binary rep of the string
    temp = str.encode(sandboxAPIKey + sandboxSharedSecret + repr(int(time.time())))
    print(temp)

    authHash.update(temp)

    #look at the string representation of the binary digest
    print(authHash.digest())

    #now I want to look at the string representation of the digest
    print(bytes.decode(authHash.digest()))
```

Here is the output of a run (with the sig and key information changed from the real output)

```
b'sdwe5yxkwewvr9j343434385gkbH4343h4343dz129443643474'
b'\x945EM3\xf5\xa6\xf6\x92\xd1\r\xa5K\xa3IO'

print(bytes.decode(authHash.digest()))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I am assuming I am not getting something right with my call to decode but I can not figure out what it is. The print of the authHash.digest looks like valid to me.

I would really appreciate any ideas on how to get this to work

Comment: **1.3.1**?! That dates to somewhere in the mid to late 90s. Where did you even find a version of Python that old, let alone for Ubuntu? Surely you mean 3.1.1?

Comment: Whoooa - picked a bad week to stop sniffing glue. Yeah I meant 3.1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you try to decode a bytearray into a string it tries to match sequentially the bytes to valid characters of an encoding set(by default, utf-8), the exception is being raised because it can't match a sequence of bytes to a valid character in the utf-8 alphabet.

The same will happen if you try to decode it using ascii, any value greater than 127 is an invalid ascii character.

So, if you are trying to get a printable version of the md5 hash, you should hexdigest it, this is the standard way of printing any type of hash, each byte is represented by 2 hexadecimal digits.

In order to do this you can use:

```
authHash.hexdigest()
```

If you need to use it in a url, you probably need to encode the bytearray into base64:

```
base64.b64encode(authHash.digest())
```

Comment: So then how do I get it from hex to ascii - the server on the other end doesn't want hex encoded it just wants the ascii representation. I tried to use binascii.a2b_hex() and binascii.unhexlify() but no luck.

Comment: you need the server to get the raw bytes? For example for md5(b'1') you have to send the server: b'\xc4\xcaB8\xa0\xb9#\x82\r\xccP\x9aou\x84\x9b'? Because this can't be turned into ascii :-/ you should send the raw bytes through the socket

Comment: Thx for the advice. Added it to my answer.